# How to remove a route in Express 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route like this :

```
app.route('/internal/api/services').get(function(req, res, next) {

    var query = servicesModel.find(null);

    query.exec(function (err, services) {
      if (err) { throw err; }

      console.log("getting all services");

      res.json(services);

    });

});
```

How can I programmatically remove this route by path ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried looking into the Express source code? `express/lib/router/index.js` looks interesting. May I ask you why you want to remove a route during runtime? You may also ignore it if some condition is met. This would be a lot better because the API resource/call you provide will speak to you or another developer with say a `403` or `404`.

Comment: I have the same question. Responding to try-catch-finally, I would say that my app reads from a config.json file that can define behavior, including eliminating certain routes altogether. Although I could attempt it using a middleware intercept, other things fall together more smoothly if express is simply aware that the route is gone.